# Do we consider this question on topic

Tags: discussion

According to [this](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/the-7-essential-meta-questions-of-every-beta/) it states:

> Don’t ask about…
>
> Questions that are primarily opinion-based

This [question](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/124/why-do-some-people-sneer-at-starbucks-coffee) I think is likely to elicit opinions and subjective answers and probably should be considered off topic.

Do we think these types of questions should be considered on topic for this site?

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what is opinion-based about the question?

Comment: Well in my view you're asking about a perceived snobbery and opinion about a coffee chain and asking why they wouldn't purchase a product. On top of this it's very open and likely to elicit opinions in that it's unlikely to yield answers that are facts. It's not comparing 2 or more products, it's saying why don't a certain bunch of people don't buy a specific product. If you were going to ask why buy mac vs a windows pc and list the pros and cons of each that would be different but it could still fail the test of too many answers, anyway I'm interested in the community thoughts on this

Comment: As far as I'm aware, I'm asking about the reasons given by a [substantiated](http://ideas.time.com/2012/09/19/the-perils-of-coffee-snobbery/) group of people for avoiding Starbucks coffee. As TimPost shows in his answer, there are valid and factual reasons they give for disliking the coffee. (Also, just to make it clear: I'm not trying to wind anyone up, I'm trying to ask difficult questions during Private Beta so that these things can be clarified) :)

Comment: Which is why I posted this meta question to clarify this, IMO this is a question that is going to elicit opinions, for instance I don't drink in Starbucks but for me it's a taste and service issue. Tim's answer doesn't to me contain any facts it's an opinion, you can buy espresso in starbucks so I don't see what relevance the part about hot water and milk has unless it just means they don't like the majority of their offerings. We're still early days into this beta and I for one am very happy this exists which is why I'm active, I love my coffee :).

Answer (score 4):

There has to be *some* leeway sometimes.

For example in the [SFF-Stack](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/) there is an "Off-Topic" close reason of:

> Questions seeking **scientific solutions or explanations** are off-topic unless they relate directly to a cited work of fiction. There are a number of other Stack Exchange sites dedicated to answering questions on non-fictional sciences.

[image: Scientific-Off-Topic.JPG]

But there are several questions which ask for purely 'scientific explanations' which have been left open (after much discussion). Some of them are even considered to be the site's most popular questions. Examples:

- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/43651/is-sheldon-right-that-superman-would-have-killed-lois-when-he-caught-her
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/28862/how-did-the-cookfire-get-hot-enough-to-melt-gold-in-game-of-thrones
- https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/72925/why-is-there-no-electricity-available-in-the-walking-dead-series

As long as we define what we can allow, and what we can't.

I suggest that we let the question sit for a little while, see what types of answers pop-up. If the answers are low quality / primarily opinion-based, then we can surmise that the question is not a good fit for this site.

Comment: Well we are in beta so these things can be thrashed out, I'm not 100% sure on this, I've not voted to close this question but I see others have but it's important to lay the ground rules and get buy in from the community I appreciate that we don't have to stick to the rules or be flexible but I don't want the site to degrade if it can be helped

Comment: There is a good answer to this question, I think it should be left.